# Dot env file comparison/validation

Tags: shell, awk, dotenv

If you have multiple `.env` files in a given directory for specific environments e.g. `dev.env`, `staging.env` and `prod.env`, using a shell, is it possible to check that each file has the same env var keys, ignoring the values?

For example, given the following files:

`dev.env`

```
KEY_1=DEV_VALUE_1
KEY_2=DEV_VALUE_2
```

`staging.env`

```
KEY_1=STAGING_VALUE_1
KEY_2=STAGING_VALUE_2
```

`prod.env`

```
KEY_1=PROD_VALUE_1
KEY_2=PROD_VALUE_2
KEY_3=PROD_VALUE_3
```

Can anyone suggest an `awk` command or similar that would return a non-zero exit code due to `prod.env` containing an extra key? The goal here is to validate that all `.env` files are aligned in the keys they declare, primarily in a CI setting.

Comment: Do all files except `prod.env` always have three lines?

Comment: Why not use whatever language you are using that has a dotenv parser?

Comment: @Cyrus no, the expectation is that all `.env` files have the same number of keys. A naive approach could be just to check each file has the same number of lines, but that could be a problem if a key was mistakenly renamed in one file but not another.

Comment: @chepner this sanity check validation would happen in a CI setting and is not project specific. I'd prefer to manage this in the shell if possible before falling back to the language used by a given project.

Comment: You can choose any language with a dotenv parser you like, independent of whatever a particular project uses. My point is that `awk` is not an appropriate choice as that language, but you clearly have *a* language with such a parser that you are familiar with.

Comment: @chepner I understand I could use a language of my choice, however I was hoping I could achieve my goal using a GNU utility. As you say `awk` probably isn't the best choice.

Comment: The standard utilities are all decades older than modern file formats, and none of them are really appropriate for writing parsers. (There's a reason tools like `yacc` were created instead of just reusing `awk` et al.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, count the files for each key, and show discrepancies.

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f

{
    keys[$1]++
}

END {
    for( key in keys ) {
        if( n == 0 ) {
            n = keys[key]
        }

        if( keys[key] != n ) {
            printf "%s appears in %d of %d files\n", \
            key, keys[key], n > "/dev/stderr"
        }
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -F= -f ./missing.awk *.env
KEY_3 appears in 1 of 3 files
```

Comment: Ah ha! Perfect, just what I was trying looking for, Thanks James!

Comment: I was thinking along the same lines. One way to defeat this is to have a key appear multiple times in a single file.

Comment: @glennjackman, quite so.  I'm also assuming every line contains an '=' assignment to an environment variable.  Duplicates are easily coped with, though.  Keep a separate count of keys for the current file, and don't add duplicates to the global count.  Reset the per-file count whenever FILENAME changes.

Comment: This fails for multiline values and comments containing `=`. `awk` processes the file one *line* at a time, not one key-value pair at a time.

Comment: (Aside from that, you may as well set `FS` in a `BEGIN` block rather than requiring the caller to use `-F` and `-f` when running `awk`.)

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone suggest an `awk` command or similar that would return a
> non-zero exit code due to `prod.env` containing an extra key?

I would harness GNU AWK for this task following way

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="=";PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"}FNR==1{delete arr1}{arr1[$1]}ENDFILE{keys="";for(i in arr1){keys = keys FS i};arr2[keys];if(length(arr2)>1){exit(1)}}' *.env
```

Explanation: I inform GNU `AWK` that field separator is `=` and that array should be traversed with sorted indices. On starting line of each line I do clear array `arr1`, then for each line mention key being value of 1st column of array `arr1`, after processing file, I do build string `keys` by concatenating keys of `arr1` using field separator. Here order of traverse is important as it provides that 2 files with same keys in different order will give same string. Then I use this string as key of `arr2` and if there more than 1 different keys in `arr2` I do exit with non-zero code as stipulated by requirements.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version that not only will inform you of mis-aligned keys, but also show you what their values are, and from which .env file :

```
 mawk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="="
             __++ 
     } __~FNR {++____; _=FILENAME 
     }        {
             ___[$__]=___[$__]""_""FS""($NF)" | "
     } END { 
            _____=" %s only shows up at ::: %s\n"
        for(__ in ___) {

             _=___[__] 
             sub("[ ]*[|][ ]*$","",_)
             
             if(____!=gsub(FS,"&",_)) {
                   printf(_____,__,_) } } }' test*.env | lgp3

    KEY_3 only shows up at ::: testprod.env=PROD_VALUE_3
```